# Soft shadow has an unintended offset

Tags: three.js, shadow

I'm currently working on a soft / blurred shadow effect that is casted on a plane directly under my object (just for giving it some more depth). The light source (DirectionalLight) shares the center coordinates of the object but with an offset in Y, so that it's straight above. It is pointing down to the center of the object.

I experimented a little bit with the shadow parameters of the light and found out that lowering the shadow map size gives me quite a nice soft shadow effect which would be sufficient for me. For example:

```
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 32;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 32;
```

However, i noticed that there is an offset to the shadow which lets the observer assume that the light source is not coming directly from above:

[image]

I created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/k7huyvzr/1/) fiddle from which i created the image. As shadow type i use the PCFSoftShadowMap.

With this setup I would assume that the shadow effect is equally casted on all four sides of the cube, but it's obviously not. I also noticed that this 'offset' gets smaller when increasing the shadow map size and is barely noticable when using for example sizes like 512 or 1024.

This method would be an easy and performant solution for the desired effect, so I really appreciate any help on this

**EDIT:**

As stated out in the comments, tweaking the radius of the LightShadow isn't a satisfiying solution because the shadow gradient has hard edges instead of soft ones.

Answer (score 3):

I think what is happening is that your shadowmap is low enough resolution, that you're seeing rounding error. If you switch back to THREE.BasicShadowMap, I think you will see that the physical lightmap pixels being hit happen to lie on the side of the object that you're seeing the larger edge, and as you move the object, the shadow will move in steps the size of the pixels on the map.

Generally in practice, you want to use a higher res lightmap, and keep its coverage area as tight around the focal point of your scene as possible to give you the most resolution from the lightmap. Then you can tweak the .radius of  of the LightShadow to get the right softness.

Comment: I added some animation to the cube position so you can see the rounding error better as the object moves.
http://jsfiddle.net/manthrax/39benwty/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think i understand what the problem is. I tried to follow your advice here: http://jsfiddle.net/k7huyvzr/2/ . However, i am not satisfied with tweaking the radius of the LightShadow since it doesn't give me a soft blurr effect but more a hard one.

Comment: Yeah.. unfortunately there isn't a control that I know of that lets us increase the number of samples for the shadowmapping. If this is a static scene, I might recommend pre-baking the shadows into the textures in some kind of modelling tool like blender?

Answer (score 1):

One solution i came up with is using four light sources, all with a very slight positional offset, so that the 'shadow-offset' would come from four different directions (http://jsfiddle.net/683049eb/):

```js
// a basic three.js scene

var container, renderer, scene, camera, controls, light, light2, light3, light4, cubeCenter, cube;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xccccff);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 200, 800);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    // (camera) controls
    // mouse controls: left button to rotate, 
    // mouse wheel to zoom, right button to pan
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  var size = 100;
    
    // ambient light
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.333);
    scene.add(ambient);

    // mesh
    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(size, size, size);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });
    
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
    cube.position.y = size / 2.0;
    cube.castShadow = true;
    cube.receiveShadow = false;
    scene.add(cube);
    
    // Get bounding box center
    var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(cube);
    cubeCenter = new THREE.Vector3();
    boundingBox.getCenter(cubeCenter);
    
    var position1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, size * 2, 0.0000001);
    createDirectionalLight(scene, 0.15, position1, size, cubeCenter);
    var position2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, size * 2, -0.0000001);
    createDirectionalLight(scene, 0.15, position2, size, cubeCenter);
    var position3 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0000001, size * 2, 0);
    createDirectionalLight(scene, 0.15, position3, size, cubeCenter);
    var position4 = new THREE.Vector3(-0.0000001, size * 2, 0);
    createDirectionalLight(scene, 0.15, position4, size, cubeCenter);
    
  // shadow plane
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500, 100, 100);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        // opacity: 0.6,
        color: 0x65bf32,
        side: THREE.FrontSide
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(plane);

    // events
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize(event) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function createDirectionalLight(scene, intensity, position, cameraSize, targetPosition) {
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, intensity);
    light.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    light.target.position.set(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);
    light.target.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    light.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(light);
    
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 32;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 32;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -cameraSize;
    light.shadow.camera.right = cameraSize;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -cameraSize;
    light.shadow.camera.top = cameraSize;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 1.0;
    light.shadow.camera.far = cameraSize * 3;
    light.shadow.bias = 0.0001;
    scene.add(new THREE.CameraHelper(light.shadow.camera));
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

[image]